# Do I have enough SD storage on my new 2ds xl for updates

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I recently bought a new 2ds xl and was wondering if I buy the physical version of Pokemon Sun will I have enough SD space to install the updates for the game?

Answer (score 1):

If your SD card has at least 294 open blocks of space, you should be fine. The extra data takes up only 4 blocks of space, so Pokemon Sun would take around 300 blocks of storage in total.

Answer (score -1):

You should have plenty of space to install the patches.

Comment: I just realized you're using a physical copy. I've edited my answer to reflect this information.